# How to test Azure HTTP Trigger Function in Jest and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, ts-jest

I am following this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#javascript-in-vs-code

and I need to test one of my Azure Function, written in TypeScript. I have following files in the same **test/** folder.

**DefaultContext.js**

```
module.exports = {
    log: jest.fn()
};
```

**GetAnnouncements.test.ts**

```
import httpTrigger from '../GetAnnouncements/index'
const context = require('defaultContext');

test('Get announcements', async () => {

    const request = {
        query: { name: 'Bill' }
    };

    await httpTrigger(context, request);

    expect(context.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(context.res.body).toEqual('Hello Bill');
});
```

When I run **npm test** the second line is throwing error

```
 Cannot find module 'defaultContext' from 'tests/GetAnnouncements.test.ts'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './defaultContext.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'].
```

what does it mean? How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the defaultContext file path as below with rest of the code:

```
const httpFunction = require('./index');
const context = require('../testing/defaultContext')

test('Http trigger should return known text', async () => {

    const request = {
        query: { name: 'Bill' }
    };

    await httpFunction(context, request);

    expect(context.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(context.res.body).toEqual('Hello Bill');
});
```

Later add this to jest config

```
"modulePaths": [
  "<rootDir>"
],
```