# How to unit test azure durable function in javascript for v4?

Tags: javascript, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

how to write unit test case of this durable function. it is calling through app and df, so it does not have any function. how can i call the trigger and orchestrator? Here is my code

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const df = require('durable-functions');

const { autoDeleteBackUpActivity, autoDeleteBackUpDeterminer } = require('../activity/autoDeleteBackUpActivity');

df.app.orchestration('AutoDeleteBackupOrchestrator', function* (context) {
  const backupDatabasesToBeRemoved = yield context.df.callActivity('AutoDeleteBackUpDeterminer');

  const parallelTasks = [];
  for (const backupDatabase of backupDatabasesToBeRemoved) {
    parallelTasks.push(
      context.df.callActivity(
        'AutoDeleteBackUpActivity',
        backupDatabase
      )
    );
  }
  if (parallelTasks.length > 0) {
    yield context.df.Task.all(parallelTasks);
  }
});

df.app.activity('AutoDeleteBackUpDeterminer', {
  handler: autoDeleteBackUpDeterminer
});

df.app.activity('AutoDeleteBackUpActivity', {
  handler: autoDeleteBackUpActivity
});

app.timer('AutoDeleteBackupTimerTrigger', {
  schedule: '0 0 2 * * *',
  extraInputs: [df.input.durableClient()],
  handler: async (myTimer, context) => {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    const instanceId = await client.startNew('AutoDeleteBackupOrchestrator');
    context.log('[Auto-Delete-Backup]: Started orchestration with ID: ', instanceId);
  }
});
```

is there any testing util is available for v4 javascript durable function? how we can write unit test case of these code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **`Jest`** library to Create Unit Test for Azure Function, Just install the **`jest`** package from **`npm`**. Create one **`Tests folder`** and a **`test file with js extension`** inside it, Then run the **`npx jest`** command to run the test:-

**Install jest package:-**

```
npm i jest
npx jest
```

In your Function project create one folder and add js file:- **`__tests__/autoDeleteBackup.test.js`** file:-

**`autoDeleteBackup.test.js:-`**

```js
// __tests__/autoDeleteBackup.test.js

const { AutoDeleteBackupOrchestrator } = require('../src/functions/autoDeleteBackup');
const { autoDeleteBackUpActivity, autoDeleteBackUpDeterminer } = require('../activity/autoDeleteBackUpActivity');

// Mocking the durable-functions module
jest.mock('durable-functions', () => {
    const mDurableFunctions = {
        df: {
            callActivity: jest.fn(),
            Task: {
                all: jest.fn((tasks) => Promise.all(tasks)),
            },
        },
        app: {
            orchestration: jest.fn(),
            activity: jest.fn(),
            timer: jest.fn(),
        },
        input: {
            durableClient: jest.fn(),
        },
        getClient: jest.fn(),
    };
    return mDurableFunctions;
});

describe('AutoDeleteBackupOrchestrator', () => {
    test('should call AutoDeleteBackUpDeterminer and AutoDeleteBackUpActivity for each backup database', async () => {
        const context = {}; // Mock context object
        const backupDatabasesToBeRemoved = ['database1', 'database2', 'database3'];
        const mockCallActivity = jest.fn();

        // Mocking callActivity functions
        const df = require('durable-functions');
        df.df.callActivity.mockImplementation((activityName, backupDatabase) => {
            mockCallActivity(activityName, backupDatabase);
            return Promise.resolve();
        });

        // Call the orchestrator function
        await AutoDeleteBackupOrchestrator(context);

        // Expect AutoDeleteBackUpDeterminer to be called once
        expect(df.df.callActivity).toHaveBeenCalledWith('AutoDeleteBackUpDeterminer');

        // Expect AutoDeleteBackUpActivity to be called for each backup database
        expect(mockCallActivity.mock.calls.length).toBe(backupDatabasesToBeRemoved.length);
        backupDatabasesToBeRemoved.forEach((backupDatabase, index) => {
            expect(mockCallActivity.mock.calls[index][0]).toBe('AutoDeleteBackUpActivity');
            expect(mockCallActivity.mock.calls[index][1]).toBe(backupDatabase);
        });

        // Expect df.Task.all to be called once with parallelTasks array
        expect(df.df.Task.all).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Array));
    });
});
```

Now, ***Run the command below***:-

```bash
npx jest
```

***Output:-***

[image]

**Azure Durable Function Javascript v4 Durable Orchestrator Default Function** code Test:-

```js
// __tests__/durableHello1.test.js

const { durableHello1Orchestrator } = require('../src/functions/durableHello1');

// Mocking the durable-functions module
jest.mock('durable-functions', () => {
    const mDurableFunctions = {
        df: {
            callActivity: jest.fn(),
        },
        app: {
            orchestration: jest.fn(),
            activity: jest.fn(),
            http: jest.fn(),
        },
        input: {
            durableClient: jest.fn(),
        },
        getClient: jest.fn(),
    };
    return mDurableFunctions;
});

describe('durableHello1Orchestrator', () => {
    test('should return outputs containing greetings for given cities', async () => {
        const context = {}; // Mock context object
        const expectedOutputs = ['Hello, Tokyo', 'Hello, Seattle', 'Hello, Cairo'];
        
        // Mocking callActivity function
        const df = require('durable-functions');
        df.df.callActivity.mockResolvedValueOnce('Hello, Tokyo');
        df.df.callActivity.mockResolvedValueOnce('Hello, Seattle');
        df.df.callActivity.mockResolvedValueOnce('Hello, Cairo');
        
        const result = await durableHello1Orchestrator(context);
        
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedOutputs);
    });
});
```

*Output:-*

[image]

Reference:-

[Azure function nodejs v4 test mode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415117/azure-function-nodejs-v4-test-mode/76429719#) My answer