# how to mock HttpRequest body and InvocationContext of @azure/functions with jest in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, jestjs, azure-functions

I have below function and I want to write a test but couldn't find a way to mock HttpRequest

```
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
export async function create(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {  
  context.log(`addFeedback processing request for url "${request.url}, ${context.invocationId}"`);
  // get product list from cosmosdb 
  return {
    status: 200,
    jsonBody: {
      product,
    },
  };
```

How to mock InvocationContext and HttpRequest and test this function in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use **Jest to Mock** your Azure Functions Javascript HttpTrigger** refer my [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415117/azure-function-nodejs-v4-test-mode/76429719#76429719)

**`Install the Jest dependency:-`**

```js
npm install @azure/functions jest supertest --save-dev
```

***My Azure Function HttpTrigger:-***

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

        return { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };
    }
});
```

***My index.test.js:-***

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

describe('Azure Function Tests', () => {
    it('should respond with "Hello, world!" for GET request without name parameter', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .get('/api/httpTrigger1')
            .expect(200);
        expect(response.text).toBe('Hello, world!');
    });

    it('should respond with "Hello, John!" for GET request with name parameter', async () => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .get('/api/httpTrigger1')
            .query({ name: 'John' })
            .expect(200);
        expect(response.text).toBe('Hello, John!');
    });

    // Add more test cases as needed
});
```

**Output:-**

Run **`npx jest`**:-

[image]